# Licenciamento do MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, postgresql, licença

Estou começando a desenvolver um sistema que rodara em Android, Web e Windows. As 3 versões deverão conversar entre si e as três versões terão as mesmas funções será um port de uma mesma aplicação para 3 plataformas.

O sistema será desenvolvido em C# mas não sei qual banco de dados escolher na verdade minha maior duvida é quanto ao licenciamento, não e não posso aumentar o custo para o meu cliente ou seja não posso pedir pra ele comprar uma licença de alguns milhares de reais para que ele possa usar o meu sistema. Com isso eu resumi minha lista de banco de dados para 2 ou vou usar MySQL ou o PostgreSQL. O PostgreSQL sei que é totalmente free. Mas o MySQL me sugiram algumas duvidas.

O MySQL tem a grande vantagem de eu já trabalhar com ele a algum tempo e dele ter algumas ferramentas que facilitam e muito o desenvolvimento e a administração do banco de dados. Depois desta ladainha toda vem a pergunta.

Posso distribuir o MySQL junto com o meu sistema sem ter que pagar nenhuma licença?

Meu cliente não corre o risco de ter que pagar uma licença ou ser acusado de pirataria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [versão community do MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/) está sob a licensa de código livre [GPLv2](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License).

Você pode usar o mysql de graça. A única coisa que você não pode fazer ´e fazer modificações no MySQL sem republicá-las como código aberto.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, você pode distribuir o MySQL junto com sua aplicação sem nenhum problema para você ou para seu cliente.

Eu só não vou dizer sem risco futuro algum porque estamos falando de um produto da Oracle, a empresa que faz mais dinheiro com advogados do que com engenheiros.

É claro que se um dia ela se voltar contra o usuários gratuitos do produto será possível migrar para um produto similar que não chamará MySQL já que a marca é da Oracle mas que funcionará de forma idêntica. De fato hoje algumas pessoas preferem usar o [MariaDB](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) no lugar do MySQL por causa disto.

Note que quase ninguém está muito preocupado com isto ou porque acham que a Oracle não fará nada ou porque se fizer terá um boa saída para o problema.

Comment: E como a Oracle iria ir atŕas dos usuários do mysql? O código está publicado sob a GPL afinal de contas...

Comment: O código é diferente do produto. Como você deve saber a licença GPL não exige que o produto seja gratuito. Inclusive um produto gratuito pode deixar de ser.

Comment: o produto não precisa ser gratuíto mas qualquer outra pessoa pode compilar e distribuir o mysql gratuitamente se ela quiser.

Comment: Não pode, você está está enganado. Uma pessoa pode usar o código que é usado no MySQL, mas o MySQL é de propriedade da Oracle. E só a parte que é GPL deste código pode ser usado para este fim. Hoje há partes não GPL em diversos adendos ao MySQL que são úteis para algumas pessoas.