# MySQL = MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mariadb

Já faz alguns dias em que esculto nas minhas aulas o professor dizendo:

> A oracle comprou o `MySQL` e apenas o renomeou para `MariaDB`.

Como não sou de acreditar fácil nas coisas faladas, fui pesquisar sobre o assunto e pelo pouco que li, entendi que não houve essa "substituição" e que `MySQL` e `MariaDB` não são o mesmo.

Afinal, o `DB` `MySQL` é a mesma coisa que o `MariaDB`? Se não, qual a diferença entre eles?

Comment: Seu professor esta totalmente enganado, MariaDB é compativel em muitas coisas com MySql, quase todos bancos de dados mais simples poderão funcionar em ambos (com um ou outro ajustes). O MariaDB se eu não me engano tem suporte para innoDB e myIsam, mesmos motores usados no mysql, mas também possui um motor chamado XtraDB

Comment: Você pode dar uma lida [aqui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql). Resumindo: MariaDB é um fork(cópia) de MySQL. MariaDB afirma trazer algumas melhorias sobre o MySQL e que o MariaDB é mantido pela Oracle e MariaDB é mantido pelos os desenvolvedores do MySQL.

Comment: [Diferença de resultado entre MySql 5.5 e MariaDB 5.5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72171/91)

Comment: Achei interessante o que li na Wikipedia uma vez, acho que vale a pena: [Wikipedia MariaDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB)

Comment: O criador do MySQL e MariaDB está ficando sem filhos para nomear bancos de dados =P

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145655/132

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72171/132

Comment: Ele não poderia estar mais errado. Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45115/101. Tem informação útil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41672/101.

Comment: @Maniero muito bom, gostei da sua resposta do primeiro [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45115/licenciamento-do-mysql) relacionado

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seu professor está enganado, *MariaDB* é compatível em muitas coisas com *MySql*, mas não é nada renomeado, é outro banco de qualquer forma, pode ser até considerado uma fork do mysql, já que foi criado pelo mesmo desenvolvedor do mysql.

Ou seja são projetos a parte, tanto que ambos recebem atualizações, melhorias e correções independente um do outro.

A maioria das estruturas de banco simples criadas para Mysql poderão funcionar no MariaDB e vice-versa (com um ou outro ajustes as vezes sendo necessário). O *MariaDB* se eu não me engano tem suporte para *innoDB* e myIsam, mesmos motores usados no mysql, mas também possui um motor chamado **[XtraDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradb-and-innodb/)** (note que apesar de não ser padrão no Mysql é possivel usa-lo nele também, mas isto é outra história).

O MySql **agora** pertence a **empresa [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/)** e é mantido ainda e continua sendo desenvolvido e evoluiu bastante desde que virou um produto dela, já o **mariaDB** é mantido pelas empresas **MariaDB Corporation Ab** e **MariaDB Foundation** (conforme wikipédia).

No link a seguir contém as incompatibilidades entre ambos (a partir das versões MariaDB 5.1 e MySQL 5.1):

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Incompatibilidade nas versões MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 5.7 (creio que sejam as mais recentes):

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-102-and-mysql-57/

---

### Um resumo breve da história do porque nasceu o MariaDB

Mysql foi criada pelo *Michael "Monty" Widenius* e *David Axmark*, a [*Sun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) adquiriu a empresa [*Mysql AB*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_AB), adquirindo assim o produto mysql, *Michael* trabalhou inicialmente para eles, mas ficou insatisfeito, não sei dizer se foi com o resultado do projeto ou com a empresa em si, e por isto deixou a **Sun**.

A *Sun* que foi fundada em 1982 então foi absorvida pela empresa [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/) entre 2009 e 2010, deixando assim de existir e os produtos que a ela pertenciam, como *Java* e o *Mysql*, passaram a pertencer a [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/).

Em 2009 mesmo *Monty* (Michael) criou uma fork (*'cópia'*) do Mysql dando a este sistema o nome de sua filha, Maria, e assim nascia o MariaDB.

Em meados de 2012 Monty (Michael) junto com David criaram a empresa [MariaDB Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB)

---

### Concluindo

Mysql e MariaDB podem ser compatíveis em quase tudo, mas possuem diversas incompatibilidades atualmente.

- O Mysql é mantido e continua a evoluir pelas "mãos" da **Oracle**.
- O MariaDB é mantido e continua a evoluir pelas "mãos" de **MariaDB Corporation Ab** e **MariaDB Foundation**.

Ambos são desenvolvidas atualmente por empresas diferentes, sem quaisquer ligação e creio que assim podemos considerar ambos sistemas concorrentes.

Comment: Pode ser considerado não, é mesmo. Resultado do MySQL ser comprado pela Oracle (ou pela Sun, não lembro). Aí o criador do MySQL achou que não iriam honrar o nome da filha dele (My), então ele resolveu lançar outro banco para fazer a devida homenagem a sua outra filha (Maria).

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu ia colocar o back da historinha dele, da filha dele e etc, mas achei que iria fugir do foco de interesse da pergunta, estou no momento tentando traduzir a lista de incompatibilidades para postar em portugues aqui.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento gostei da resposta, mas vamos ver se eu realmente entendi, os dois foram criados pelos mesmos criadores, mas o `MySQL` é mantido pela e o `MariaDB` por outra corporação? Ou seja, mesmo que sejam praticamente iguais, são dois bancos diferentes (não houve renomeação e sim o surgimento de um novo `DB`).

Comment: @JorgeMatheus, Maria é aberto/da comunidade, My é da Oracle. Maria eu vejo tendo mais avanços e mais rápidos do que o My, aceita CTEs faz bem mais tempo. Ambos acabam que ainda importam/podem importar código um do outro (licenças compatíveis para essa migração)

Comment: @JorgeMatheus mysql pertence a [**Oracle**](https://www.oracle.com), todas ultimas atualizações foram criadas pela Oracle... MariaDB pertence a **MariaDB Corporation Ab** e **MariaDB Foundation**, que provavelmente pertence ao criador original do mysql e do mariaDB. Mysql foi criado muito antes do mariaDB e não pertencia a Oracle, a Sun (um antiga empresa que era dona do Java) adquiriu o Mysql e algum tempo depois a Sun foi absorvida pela empresa Oracle, então o Mysql passou a pertencer a Oracle, o autor original ficou com medo do Mysql deixar de ser livre e resolveu criar uma FORK.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado show! Bom saber a parte de que o `MariaDB` é  "aberto".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Desculpa a ignorância, vi que utilizou bastante o termo `FORK`, o que seria?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus fork é uma 'copia' de um código aberto geralmente, que passa a ser desenvolvidor por outra pessoa ou pela mesma pessoa mas com algum objetivo diferente do original, podendo muitas vezes se tornar muito distante do original.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, show!!! Agora ficou ainda mais claro que o `MariaDB` é uma cópia do `MySQL` mas é mantido/desenvolvido por outra empresa. Obrigado !

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento muito obrigado pela sucinta explicação, agora estou totalmente apto para falar sobre o assunto e quem sabe até contar a "história" por trás para o meu professor :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Muito bom! Creio que essa resposta irá ajudar outras pessoas que estiverem com essa mesma dúvida que eu estava.Mais uma vez, obrigado pelo tempo dedicado.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus você não está totalmente apto a falar sobre o assunto, mas já tem informações corretas que ajudam muito nisso.

Comment: @Maniero me precipitei ao dizer isso, queria dizer: Apto a poder dizer que `MySQL` e `MariaDB` não são apenas um.

Answer (score 5):

Em 2008, o projeto MySql foi incorporado pela Sun Microsystems. Em 2009, a Oracle comprou a Sun - e incorporou o MySql em seu rol de produtos. Não houve mudança no nome do produto. ([Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)).

O fundador do projeto, descontente com a situação, realizou um fork do MySql criando assim o MariaDB. ([Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB))

Pelo fato do MariaDB ser um fork do MySql, ambos (ainda) compartilham boa parte do código-fonte. Aparentemente, o projeto MariaDB tem se esforçado em manter-se altamente compatível com as novas versões do MySql (para seduzir usuários deste à migração daquele). Essa compatibilidade inclui sintaxe Sql, sistema de arquivos e protocolos de comunicação. Ou seja, na prática você inclusive pode usar um client de MySql para comunicar-se com o MariaDB, observados os devidos pareamentos de versão. ([Fonte](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/))